# rsync on mac move and delete certain files

Tags: macos, terminal, rsync, photo, file-management

I have folders & subfolders organized by date in the name containing files .jpgs and .arw. I want to keep the same folder structure but move the ARW files to a copy of the folder structure AND delete them out of the source directory. Also if the folder does not contain any .ARW files it would not be copied.

I was working on something like this that I could run in the terminal screen:

```
rsync -av --exclude=.*/ --include=‘*/‘ --include=‘*.arw’  --exclude=‘*’ /Users/adam/test1/ /Users/Adam/test2/
```

But in my testing it's copying both the .jpg and .arw file to test 2. My assumption would be that I would add --remove-source-files once I got the code working with only moving the ARW file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command is:

```
rsync -avm --remove-source-files --include='*.arw' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /Users/adam/test1 /Users/adam/test2
```

The option 'm' prevents the copy of the empty directories.

You can run rsync with the '--dry-run' option to see which files would be copied without actually execute it:

```
rsync -avm --dry-run --remove-source-files --include='*.arw' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /Users/adam/test1 /Users/adam/test2
```

Comment: So that just created the target directory of test2 but it didn't search the subfolder (2015_02_12) for the photo file extension and move them as well. The source directory is test1 -> 2015_02_12 -> Photo Files

Answer (score 0):

It appears rsync has an issue with .ARW file type. Changed requirement to move JPEG files instead to the new directory.

rsync -am --remove-source-files --include=‘*.jpeg’ --include='*.jpg' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /Users/adam/test\ 1/ /Users/Adam/test2/

Thanks!